# Как отключить обработчик события элемента находящего под элементом по которому кликнули?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой код:

```html
<div style="background-color: red; height: 100px;" onclick="alert('а меня не должно быть!');">
  <div style="background-color: blue; height: 50px;" onclick="alert('это нужный клик')">click here</div>
</div>
```

нужно, что бы при клике по синему блоку отключился обработчик красного блока, а потом вернуть его на место.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation`

```html
<div style="background-color: red; height: 100px;" onclick="alert('а меня не должно быть!');">
  <div style="background-color: blue; height: 50px;" onclick="event.stopPropagation();alert('это нужный клик')">click here</div>
</div>
```